# How to read the second line in a document.txt and then make a loop that reads line +1 in this document

Tags: ruby, watir

My bot reads emails one by one from a document.txt file and after login with this email the bot outputs the comments that I have in another file.

I have reached the point that the bot reads the emails but I want that a specific account makes a specific and not a repeated comment.

So I have in mind the solution of reading a specific line from the comments file.

For example account 1 reads and puts line 1 of the comments file. I want to know how can I read the second line from a comments file.

*This is the code part when I read comments one by one but I want to read for example line two or three!*

```
file = 'comments.txt'
File.readlines(file).each do |line|
    comment = ["#{line}"] 
    comment.each { |val| 
        comment = ["#{val}"] 
}
end
```

Answer (score 3):

`File.readlines` returns array. So you can do everything you want

```
lines = []

File.readlines(path_to_file, chomp: true).each.with_index(1) do |line, line_number|
  lines << (line_number == 2 ? 'Special line' : line)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below.

```
# set the line number to read
line_number = 2 # <== Reading 2nd line
comment = IO.readlines('comments.txt')[line_number-1]
```

Comment: it shows the following error : undefined local variable or method `line_number' .. can show me an example ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is overwriting the comment variable in each iteration.

I'd write your code like this:

```
lines = File.readlines('comments.txt')
lines.each do |line|
  # entire line
end
```

In the loop you can do a lot of things with the single line, unfortunately I don't get 100% what you want to do (one comment vs. multiple, always the same for specific users, etc.) I hope this helps anyway.